# How to pull data from sql, add columns to a row and insert it into another sql table?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, datatable

Hello StackOverflow Community,

I'm trying to programm some kind of Audit Trail function, which should be able to pull data from sql (only one row), add three columns to this row, and insert it into another db table (the audit trail table).

It looks something like this:

[image]

Logic:
1. SELECT * FROM 'Lace' WHERE 'macaddress' = @mac
2. Prepend the user, action and timestamp (to know when, which user did what)
3. Add the modified row into LaceAudit table.

The program looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

public class Audit2
{
    private static string _connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LaceDbConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    public enum Action
    {
        Login = 0,
        NewImageInstall = 1,
        OldImageRollback = 2,
        LocalScriptUpdate = 3,
        LaceOffline = 4,
        LaceOnline = 5,
        NewLace = 6,
        NewDepartment = 7,
        NewModel = 8,
        AlterModel = 9,
        NewHardwareId = 10,
        AlterHardwareId = 11
    };

    public static void AddToLaceAudit(string user, Action action, string mac)
    {
        // Pull Data with MAC
        DataTable dataTable = GetDataOfLace(mac);

        // Add needed columns for the new table
        dataTable.Columns.Add("user", typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add("action", typeof(int));

        // Fill in values for the new columns


        // Insert DataTable with new values to database


    }

    private static DataTable GetDataOfLace(string mac)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            DataTable _dataTable = new DataTable();

            string _query = "SELECT * FROM [Lace] WHERE [macaddress] = @mac";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(_query, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mac", mac);
            connection.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            da.Fill(_dataTable);
            connection.Close();
            da.Dispose();

            return _dataTable;
        }
    }
}
```

How can i now add values to those columns and populate the DataTable with the new values to the database? `LaceAudit` table already exists. I just need to add the modified row.

Comment: `WHERE [macaddress] = '@mac'` should be `WHERE [macaddress] = @mac`, otherwise you're looking for the macaddress `'@mac'` which explains why the `DataTable` remains empty.

Comment: yes thats right, it is like you said. i wrote it wrong in my question

Comment: Apart from that it's not relly clear what you're trying to achieve. What are _attributes_, why can't you insert records into `LaceAudit`?

Comment: I need to prepend user,action and timestamp to the row and insert it into the LaceAudit table. My problem is, that i don't know how to prepend those three attributes (user,action and timestamp) to the datatable object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to add 2 additional columns to your datatable, then get the modified row and add it to your LaceAudit table using AddToLaceAudit(). So, to prepend (add columns) do the following:

```
_dataTable.Columns.Add("user", typeof(string));
_dataTable.Columns.Add("action", typeof(Action));
```

TimeStamp columns in sql are automatically generated when a row is added / modified so this won't need to be added as a column. Reference these 2 new columns when your filling them. Then you can simply pass the DataTable (or DataRow to ensure just 1 row) to AddToLaceAudit(). Modify AddToLaceAudit to expect a DataTable (or DataRow) rather than the 3 individual variables.

If you're saying you don't know what you should be putting into these columns that's a bit more tricky. The user is often retrieved using HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name if you're creating a website or web app. As for Action, well that would depend on where you can retrieve the action performed by the user from as it's not stored in Lace. Not sure I can help you with that bit. As for timestamp that's explained above (in newer versions this is now [rowversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms182776.aspx)).

**UPDATE**

In relation to you're most recent comments you can assigned your values (that you have) to the new columns created like this:

```
_dataTable.Rows[0]["user"] = //your user value here
_dataTable.Rows[0]["action"] = //your action here
```

AddToLaceAudit would need to be modified to accept a DataTable like this:

```
AddToLaceAudit(DataTable dt)
```

To update the LaceAudit table I would suggest writing a stored procedure with your update statement and passing in the necessary variables as parameters. Looking closer at the LaceAudit table you wouldn't need to store the 'Action' as a typeof(Action) in your dataTable but as an 'int' as that's what's used in LaceAudit.

Comment: you understood it right!
after i got the row from the `Lace` table, i want to add the columns user and action + data (values) for those two columns. and then i want to add the modified row to the `LaceAudit` table

retrieving user and action ist not the problem, i got those two values.

Comment: @ElSyr - so has this answer worked? If so please mark it as the answer (click the tick next to the votes). If you're looking for more info let me know.

Comment: it's the most helpful answer yet. but i need to know how i can add values to the row and input it into the LaceAudit table which already exists. it sould be simple. i only want to get 1 row, add two values to this row and add it to another table witch already exists. i thougth datatable object would be right for this, but let me know if not :)

Comment: _dataTable["user"] = //your user value here (does not work)

Comment: @ElSyr Sorry, forgot to add the row index. Will update

Comment: thank you. i try to get the stored procedure to work, or an other solution. if i got everything to work i will mark your answer as the answer :)

Comment: @ElSyr - let me know if you need help with the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand You correctly, You'd like to be able to insert all data to the table, even if the table itself changes? 
You might select one row from the table, insert it to DataTable, and use [ColumnName property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.columnname(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: yes i would like to be able to add those three attributes and add the modified DataTable object to LaceAudit. It should be dynamical beacause i have not only this one table

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class. (Sorry I can't write in c#)

```
Public Class AuditTrail

    Private m_Mac As String
    Public Property Mac() As String
        Get
            Return m_Mac
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_Mac = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_Action As Action
    Public Property Action() As Action
        Get
            Return m_Action
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Action)
            m_Action = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_User As String
    Public Property User() As String
        Get
            Return m_User
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_User= value
        End Set
    End Property

    /*Add more properties as needed*/

    Public Function Create() As String
        Dim Result As String
        Dim SqlCmdStr As String = ("INSERT INTO LaceAudit(user, action, mac) VALUES (@User, @Action, @Mac)")
        Using SqlConn As New SqlConnection(_ConnectionString)
            Using SqlCmd As New SqlCommand(SqlCmdStr, SqlConn)
                Try
                    SqlConn.Open()
                    With SqlCmd.Parameters
                        .Clear()
                        .AddWithValue("User", User)
                        .AddWithValue("Action", Action)
                        .AddWithValue("Mac", Action)
                    End With
                    SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    Result = "Audit record successfully logged."
                 Catch ex As Exception
                     Result = ex.Message
                 Finally
                     SqlConn.Close()
                     SqlCmd.Dispose()
                     SqlConn.Dispose()
                 End Try
                 Return Result
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function

End Class
```

On the calling form / module

Instantiate the class, populate the properties, invoke the create function.

```
Private Sub CreateAuditRecord()
    Using AuditRecord As New AuditTrail
        With AuditRecord
            .User = "The user"
            .Mac = "The mac of machine the user is using"
            .Action = "The action the user committed you want to log"
            MsgBox(.Create())
        End With
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: sorry i don't want to have to add the values manually, because i have other tables with other attributes. the function needs to independently add two columns with values. and then insert the new row in a different table